# Make images in an image reel a clickable link

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm not a pro at Javascript and the works, so I just use scripts I find online. And as for this continuous image reel code I found it [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/reelslideshow.htm).
The things is, I'd like to add links to the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var firstreel=new reelslideshow({
    wrapperid: "myreel", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [800, 200], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["https://dl.dropbox.com/s/f7lt5o64j20143z/Reel-Welcome.png"], //["image_path", "optional_link", "optional_target"]
        ["https://dl.dropbox.com/s/v98on8f0qi6re57/Reel-Secret.png", "suppose i put my desired url here", "_new"]
        //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:5000, cycles:0, pauseonmouseover:true},
    orientation: "h", //Valid values: "h" or "v"
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    slideduration: 400 //transition duration (milliseconds)
})
</script>
```

I tried with the second picture, and when I right-click it the options including "Open link in new tab" can be seen. What I want though is being directed to the link once I simply click the picture.
I also tried to wrap the image URL with the `<a>` tag but of course that didn't work (I must sound really funny and idiotic by now, I'm sorry but I don't actually know what I'm doing).
Is it possible though? Thank you in advance! :)
EDIT: Here is the preview to show you what I'm talking about. http://scarlethowl.blogspot.com/

Comment: So clicking on the link doesn't work?? Or do you want to go to the URL in the same tab?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the picture. I want the image to be an image link and open in the same tab.

Comment: It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/TSb3z/. I just replaced your `_new` with `_self` so it opens in the same tab.

Comment: It does work fine in JSfiddle.. I thought this was the one but when I tried it on the actual site it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you get any errors? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: No errors, it's just that nothing happens. I already changed the `_new` to `_self` here but yeah.. still nothing. [link](http://scarlethowl.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow...
Your question is not clear...are you trying to go to a url when clicking on an image?
let's assume that the pic is : 1.jpg
the link is : www.google.com
the code goes like that:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="1.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know enough CSS and HTML to know that. This however involves Javascript so yeah.